# Raphael-free-transform looses scale value

Tags: javascript, html, plugins, raphael, transform

in the following code re-scaling of the `square` object goes wrong:
after clicking the button (which apply y-scale factor and make a rectangle out of our `square`) object displays correct BUT if you touch handles after that the previous scale values erase and square displays again.

I want to be able to make rectangle in a code and re-scale it uniformly using handles afterwards. 
How to solve this problem?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="scripts/raphael.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/raphael.free_transform.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn" onclick="onClick()">apply scale</button>
    <script>
        var r = Raphael(100, 0 , 300, 400);
        var square = r.rect(100,150, 100, 100).attr({ fill: "#aaa", stroke: "black", opacity: 0.5 });

        var ft = r.freeTransform(square, {}, function () {});
        ft.setOpts({
            attrs: { fill: 'white', stroke: '#000' },
            drag: false,
            keepRatio: ['axisX', 'axisY'],
            size: 5,
            scale: ['axisX', 'axisY'],
            rotate:false
        });

        function onClick() {
            ft.attrs.scale.y = 2;
            ft.apply();
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qvatra/Z2cqT/17/)

Comment: Is it possible to put it on a jsfiddle ?

Comment: @Ian, see the update to the question

Comment: external resource from raw.github doesn't work i put it inside code see updated js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Z2cqT/1/. It gives `setOpts undefined error`. other than that handles seems to work fine

Comment: @eguneys, I repeat your trick with copying library to source code area but I have another error: http://jsfiddle.net/qvatra/Z2cqT/4/

stupid...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you scale y by 2, it violates `keepRatio: ['axisX', 'axisY']` rule. So either you change

```
`keepRatio: false,`
```

or you scale by keeping the ratio.

## edit:

You can change the aspect ratio by `ft.attrs.ratio = 1/2` on button click. see updated js fiddle

To get js.fiddle working i added the line `r.setViewBox(0, 0, 300, 400, true);`
http://jsfiddle.net/Z2cqT/18/

Comment: found this http://geekdave.com/2013/06/19/linking-raw-github-files-from-jsfiddle/ 
.it results in http://jsfiddle.net/qvatra/Z2cqT/10/
still doesn't work but because of the another problem

Comment: Yep. good work! But it doesn't solve my problem..

in this http://jsfiddle.net/qvatra/Z2cqT/17/ you can first scale element in y direction using square handles and then scale uniformly using circle handles. It works, yes. BUT when I try to apply y scaling by pressing button and then touch circle handles the scale value erases.

Comment: I don't understand what you really need, you can control scale by code and transform handles, maybe try this `ft.attrs.scale.y = ft.attrs.scale.y * 2;`

Comment: I want quite simple functionality: 1) make rectangle out of square using button (applying scale to y)    

2) be able to rescale this rectangle uniformly by dragging circle handles. try to do it in fiddle and you will see that when you start to drag circle handles, square appears again But i want to rescale rectangle

Comment: that's exactly what happens in my jsfiddle. if you want to constantly double the size use `ft.attrs.scale.y = ft.attrs.scale.y * 2`

Comment: so you are saying that after pushing the button and dragging **only circle** handle you get rectangle as a result???? (first push button then drag)

Can't be true. I've checked it like 100 times in jsfiddle and also using notepad and chrome.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46014/discussion-between-eguneys-and-qvatra)